# How to pass qs.query to a custom plpgsql function with Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, plpgsql, django-orm

I have some queryset `qs = MyModel.objects.filter(fieldname='fieldname')` and a [custom plpgsql function](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050810133157.GA46247@winnie.fuhr.org) `my_function()`, that I can use in pg_shell like:

```sql
SELECT my_function('SELECT * FROM my_model');
```

How to do this with Django ORM? I tried to:

```py
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query, params = qs.query.sql_with_params()
    query = f"SELECT my_function('{query}')"
    cursor.execute(query, params)
```

But `qs.query.sql_with_params()` is not intended to return valid SQL.

Is something like this even possible with Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to call function/procedure do it like

```
from django.db import connections
connection = connections['default']
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.callproc('name_of_your_function', ('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE whatever_you_want', ))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
```

Next thing is about real sql query from django orm, not poor query that brings queryset.query or qs.query.sql_with_params especially in case you work with dates but the real one that will pass to psycopg

```
from .models import SomeModel
qs = SomeModel.objects.filter(create_at__gt='2021-04-20')

from django.db import connections
conn = connections['default']

from django.db.models.sql.compiler import SQLCompiler
compiler = SQLCompiler(qs.query, conn, using=qs.using)

sql, params = compiler.as_sql()
```